# Error: lexical and preprocessor issue: 'tidy.h' file not found

Tags: xcode

I encountered a preprocessor or lexical error when I tried to build my project to an archive. This did not happen on the release nor debug configuration settings on the simulator.

The message is:
`lexical and preprocessor issue: 'tidy.h' file not found`

The 'tidy.h' is included by CTidy.h, which is part of TouchXML library.

I found 'tidy.h' in a subfolder of 'iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk'. To my surprise, the file is absent in 'iPhoneOS5.1.sdk'

Is it OK for me to just copy the file to the iPhoneOS5.1.sdk?

Thanks

Comment: Everything seems to work fine if I just copy the file to iPhoneOS5.1.sdk.

Comment: I would be surprised if the app worked on the device. I would guess that you can't just copy the missing header into the iPhoneOS5.1.sdk bundle, because that won't change the fact that the header is not available on the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the:

```
 #include "tidy.h"
```

... in CTidy.h, or alternatively comment out:

```
 #include "CTidy.h"
```

That is, check to see whether the header file is really necessary.

If you find that it's not, either submit a patch to the TouchXML developers, or file a bug with them, or send them an email.

It is quite common for headers to be included unnecessarily.  For example I could write some code that depends on "foo.h", then delete my code, or refactor it in such a way that it doesn't need the header anymore, yet forget to delete the header inclusion as well.